# I can't boot my VM(Ubuntu) after linux kernel build, install

Tags: kernel

I am trying to study the Linux kernel using Virtual Box + Ubuntu
I googled how to download, build, and install the kernel version that I want and simply followed it

1. downloaded the Kernel file from kernel.org (which was in my case 5.4.92)
2. downloaded the tools that are used in kernel building
3. copied the .config file that the original kernel used
4. and followed the command
   make --> make modules --> make modules_install --> make install
5. update-initramfs and update-grub (I read somewhere that 'make install' does all this but just in case...)
6. Finally I rebooted the VM

My problem is after all this procedure 'uname -a' showed the original kernel
(which was 5.8.0-40-generic, I used Ubuntu 20.4)
And after some research, I found out how to use the Grub, and tried to boot the 5.4.92 version manually. But It showed a blank screen and stopped. (like the picture)

The State after i manually tried to boot the new kernel:
[image: The State after i manually tried to boot the new kernel]

I am aware that after I succeed in this procedure I could change some codes in the kernel file --> re-build it --> and install it
But i am stuck at the first  step...It would be really helpful if anyone could give me some hint!!

Thank you in advance
p.s if there are additional information needed to help me please inform me

Comment: You did everything a wrong way. You can find tutorials on how to build custom kernels for Ubuntu.

Comment: @Pilot6 I'm quite new to this part could you recommend any tutorials? And by meaning everything wrong, do you mean starting from installing and building too? was it the "how" I did it? Or did I start on the wrong page

Comment: Something like that https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel

Comment: You don't install kernels to Ubuntu by `make install`. You can do it, but it is a wrong way.

Comment: @Pilot6 thankyou for your feedback, I realized that my methods were not authentic and changed it to the way you advised me! But even after that The problem still occurred.  It turned out to be the 'secure boot' problem.

Comment: Secure Boot should be disabled for custom kernels.